# In Symfony2, can the validation.yml file be split into multiple files using imports?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Right now, I have a file called validation.yml with the validation of all the bundle's entities in one file.

validation.yml

```
Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank:
                message: You must enter your name
            - MaxLength: 50
        comment:
            - NotBlank:
                message: You must enter a comment
            - MinLength: 50

Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - Email:
                message: symblog does not like invalid emails. Give me a real one!
        subject:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 50
        body:
            - MinLength: 50
```

But I'd like to split it into two files and import them both.  This is what I tried and it didn't work:

validation.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: comment.yml }
    - { resource: enquiry.yml }
```

comment.yml

```
Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank:
                message: You must enter your name
            - MaxLength: 50
        comment:
            - NotBlank:
                message: You must enter a comment
            - MinLength: 50
```

enquiry.yml

```
Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - Email:
                message: symblog does not like invalid emails. Give me a real one!
        subject:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MaxLength: 50
        body:
            - MinLength: 50
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Was an exception thrown, or did nothing happen?

Comment: The form submitted without validating properly, which shouldn't have happened.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add these lines in `load` method of `src/Blogger/BlogBundle/DependencyInjection/BloggerBlogExtension.php`.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
  //...
  $yamlMappingFiles = $container->getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');
  $yamlMappingFiles[] = __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/comment.yml';
  $yamlMappingFiles[] = __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/enquiry.yml';
  $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files', $yamlMappingFiles);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked splendidly!  I even deleted that validation.yml file

Comment: @m2mdas This doesn't seem to work in xml by replacing yaml by xml. Is there a different synthax? I get the error message:  [] operator not supported for strings..

Comment: @Patt for xml the current parameter would be `validator.mapping.loader.xml_files_loader.mapping_files`.

Comment: Excellent. Your answer really exposes the flexibility of the Sf2 framework. Thank you.

Comment: This parameter was removed in Symfony 2.5 - see my answer below for updated instructions.

Answer (score 7):

## Answer added at 2015

> As of Symfony `2.7`, XML and Yaml constraint files located in the
>   `Resources/config/validation` sub-directory of a bundle are loaded.
>   Prior to `2.7`, only `Resources/config/validation.yml` (or .xml) were
>   loaded.

More info at:

- Github PR: [FrameworkBundle] "mappings" for validation [#13878](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/13878)
- Symfony doc: [The Basics of Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation)

Answer (score 6):

Symfony 2.5 broke the above solutions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210501/175753

Answer (score 5):

You can add to your services.xml

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files" type="collection">
        <parameter>Blogger\BlogBundle\Resources\config\comment.yml</parameter>
        <parameter>Blogger\BlogBundle\Resources\config\enquiry.yml</parameter>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Comment: +1. Much better then @m2mdas answer, because it only requires a simple change in the configuration. Just perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));

    $validatorFiles = $container->getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');

    $finder = new Finder();
    foreach ($finder->files()->in(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/validation') as $file) {
        $validatorFiles[] = $file->getRealPath();
    }
    $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files', $validatorFiles);
}
```

This way, using the Finder Component, you don't have to be concerned about touching this file each time you add a new validator file.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions above are not working in Symfony 2.3.

In 2.3 it's easier to load multiple Yml files from loader. For example:

```
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
    $loader->load('services/menu.yml'); //new file to load
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony **3.3** all files present in `YourBundle/Resources/config/validation/*` are registered.

---

Since Symfony **3.4** all files present in `%kernel.project_dir%/config/validator/*` are also registered.

Answer (score 1):

This is YAML alternative to @MaksSlesarenko answer.

```yaml
parameters:
  validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/CompanyName/TestBundle/Resources/config/validation/Entity.DbObject.yml"
```

BTW is there any way to change `%kernel.root_dir%/../src/CompanyName/TestBundle/` to some *bundle root* variable (like `%kernel.root_dir%`)?