# Can I add my namespace to the Symfony2 Validation routine?

Tags: validation, symfony

If I create a custom constraint and constraintvalidator in Symfony2, I have to attach it to my entity using the fully qualified name. I'm aware I can alias that name as a config variable, but I'm wondering if I can add my namespace to the ones Symfony will load from, So I can use `MyConstraint` rather than `FQDN/Path/To/MyConstraint` or `some.definition.of.myconstraint`

Answer (score 1):

In your `validation.yml` file you can add following

```
namespaces
  any_name: Path\To\Your\Validator\Namespace\
```

Then you can do

```
FQCN\Of\Entity:
  constraints:
    - "any_name:YourConstraint": ~
```

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, and thanks very much for it, but I'm not going to tick it as the answer just yet because it doesn't really meet the original questions intent. Perhaps I can add the namespaces to another config somewhere and not have to use the Prefix:Name notation?

Comment: AFAIK `namespaces` section are valid for single `validation.yml`. Perhaps you can put the entities that uses the constraint in same `validation.yml` file.

Comment: I am doing that currently, but it would be a better solution to do something akin to what zend does, and allow compilation of namespaces to look through for the requested validator.

Comment: Just checked it. Well, I was wrong. If you define `namespaces` in different file, you still get the reference of the namespace. You can not reference it without the prefix. But you can create a separate `validation_config.yml` where your namespaces will be listed. See my another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9414343/1218997).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the following in your EntityClass:

```
use FQDN/Path/To/MyConstraint AS MyConstraint;
```

Afterwards, all Classes within the MyConstraint namespace can be used within annotation:

```
@MyConstraint\SomeConstraint()
```

Comment: This is all in the Symfony2 YAML configuration, so no namespace magic to be done unfortunately.