# Load validation.yml file

Tags: symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Symfony2, can the validation.yml file be split into multiple files using imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403609/in-symfony2-can-the-validation-yml-file-be-split-into-multiple-files-using-impo)

Is there anything that need to be done before adding validation constraints in a yml file.
I struggle finding information on the doc on how to load validation.yml file:

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MinLength: 3
```

**What is the procedure to load validation constraints from a validation file?**

### EDIT

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $ymlValidationFile = $container  ->getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');
    $ymlValidationFile[] = __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/validation.yml';
        $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files',$ymlValidationFile);
}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9414343/970721) explains everything you need

Comment: Awesome, now, is there a trick to check that the file is being read? I have updated my question with what I have done. Does this sound good to you? I couldn't find any relevant info on the doc regarding this, do you know where I could learn from this dep injection for validation? Thanks

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)?

Comment: nope, thanks! post a reply so that I can accept it :-)

Comment: Is there a way to load validation.yml directly in config.yml without using semantic configuration? I tried import, but I have an error message?

Comment: And, of course, you've read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this [beautiful doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) fully explains your questions :)